# Cholesky Decomposition in the rmvnorm package

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Why is it possible to create non-singular normal random vectors by a covariance matrix which is not positive definite? e.g. its not possible to execute `chol(V)`.

```
pigeon<-data.frame(response=c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,4)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:4,each=4))
               )
m<-dcast(pigeon,subject~treatment, value.var="response")
fit<-lm(as.matrix(m[,-1])~1)
V<-cov(residuals(fit))
eigen(V)$values
rmvnorm(mean=rep(0,4),sigma=V,n=subject,method="chol")
```

Comment: There is no package called "rmvnorm". Did you mean "mvtnorm"?

Comment: You also need reshape2 for the `dcast` function; you haven't defined any variable called `subject`; and `mvtnorm::rmvnorm` did warn about an indefinite matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume you're using `mvtnorm::rmvnorm`. When you specify `method="chol"`, `rmvnorm` will use the Cholesky decomposition with pivoting. This allows for positive-semidefinite matrices, ie, some eigenvalues can be numerically zero. Emphasis on *numerically*; your smallest eigenvalue is `-2.546e-15` which while negative is is zero to the limits of precision.

If you use the default `method=eigen`, you get a matrix of `NaN`s in this case which might be closer to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

When running MASS::rmvnorm as

`rmvnorm(mu=rep(0,4),V=V,nsim=4,method="chol")` ,

I get

> Error in chol.default(V) :    the leading minor of order 4 is not
>   positive definite

, the same as running chol(V). I am using R 2.15.3. Could you clarify the question?